# basic function not working -> 'name 'happyBirthdayEmily' is not defined'

Tags: python, function

I'm following [this guide](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html) and I can't get a basic function to work.

`birthday2.py`

```
def happyBirthdayEmily(): #program does nothing as written
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
    print("Happy Birthday, dear Emily.")
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
```

So following the guide I type this:

```
>>>import birthday2
>>>happyBirthdayEmily
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'happyBirthdayEmily' is not defined
```

What Am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing parentheses after `happyBirthdayEmily` and a module reference. Do it like this:

```
>>>birthday2.happyBirthdayEmily()
```

The parens identify it as a function call, and the `birthday2.` at the beginning just says, "Use the function `happyBirthdayEmily()` from the `birthday2` module." This is structured like this, because if you had another function (not in `birthday2`) that was also called `happyBirthdayEmily()`, the python interpreter basically wouldn't know which one to use.

Comment: Everyone gave great answers but I marked this one as correct because it gave me the most background. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

you should do:

```
>>>import birthday2
>>>birthday2.happyBirthdayEmily()
```

or:

```
>>>from birthday2 import happyBirthdayEmily
>>>happyBirthdayEmily()
```

or:

```
>>>from birthday2 import *
>>>happyBirthdayEmily()
```

Read more about modules [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the full name:

```
birthday2.happyBirthdayEmily()
```

and include the `()` parethesis to call the function.

Alternatively, you can import it slightly differently:

```
from birthday2 import happyBirthdayEmily
```

to import the function into the local namespace.